# insert forward slashes into new string

Tags: php

I want to take an array of strings that look like '1234' and for each of them make a new array of stings that will look like '1/2/3/4/'

I am at basic level php and struggling with this if anyone could point me in the right direction, please. This is where I am:

```
<?php

        $mylist = array ('1234','2345','3456','4567','5678','6789');

        $newlist = array();

        while ($results = ($mylist) !== false)

            {
                print_r($mylist[0] . '\/' . [1] . '\/' . [2] . '\/' . [3] . '\/');

                $newlist[] = $results;

        echo $newlist;

            }

    ?>
```

Comment: `$newlist = array_map(function($value) { return implode('/', str_split($value)); }, $mylist);`

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` with a `\\`,

Comment: Thank you (and @cascaval). I was unable to get any of these three replies to work but I mashed them together and the result works. I will paste it below.

Answer (score 0):

Modify each array element using **[walk_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)** while replacing every digit (`\d`) in the string by applying a **[regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php)** with **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** function:

```
<?php
$mylist = array ('1234','2345','3456','4567','5678','6789');

array_walk($mylist, function(&$value, $key){
    $value = preg_replace('/(\d)/', "$1/", $value);
});
```

Alternatively, if you really want a new array, you can use **[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)**:

```
<?php
$mylist = array ('1234','2345','3456','4567','5678','6789');

$newlist = array_map(function($value){
    return preg_replace('/(\d)/', "$1/", $value);
}, $mylist);
```

Answer (score 0):

A mash of the replies above made this, which worked. Thanks so much:

```
<?php
function my_function($value)
{
    return implode('/', str_split($value));
}
    $a = array(1234, 2345, 3456);   
    print_r(array_map("my_function",$a));
?>
```